# Why does Enumerable.Empty() return an empty array?

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-objects

I expected the implementation of Enumerable.Empty() to be just this:

```
public static IEnumerable<TResult> Empty<TResult>()
{
    yield break;
}
```

But the implementation is something like this:

```
public static IEnumerable<TResult> Empty<TResult>()
{
    return EmptyEnumerable<TResult>.Instance;
}

internal class EmptyEnumerable<TElement>
{
    private static volatile TElement[] instance;

    public static IEnumerable<TElement> Instance
    {
        get
        {
            if (EmptyEnumerable<TElement>.instance == null)
                EmptyEnumerable<TElement>.instance = new TElement[0];
            return (IEnumerable<TElement>)EmptyEnumerable<TElement>.instance;
        }
    }
}
```

Why does the implementation is more complex than just one line of code? Is there an advantage to return a cached array and not (yield) return no elements?

Note: I will never rely on the implementation details of a method, but I am just curious.

Comment: `yield break` is one line in C#, but it's far more complex if you look at the generated IL code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Compiling (using LINQpad with optimizations enabled)

```
public static IEnumerable<TResult> MyEmpty<TResult>()
{
    yield break;
}
```

results in quite a lot of code.

It will create a state machine that implements the `IEnumerable` interface. Every time you call `MyEmpty` it will create a new instance of that class. Returning the same instance of an empty array is quite cheap.

The IL code for `EmptyEnumerable` is:

```
EmptyEnumerable`1.get_Instance:
IL_0000:  volatile.   
IL_0002:  ldsfld      16 00 00 0A 
IL_0007:  brtrue.s    IL_0016
IL_0009:  ldc.i4.0    
IL_000A:  newarr      04 00 00 1B 
IL_000F:  volatile.   
IL_0011:  stsfld      16 00 00 0A 
IL_0016:  volatile.   
IL_0018:  ldsfld      16 00 00 0A 
IL_001D:  castclass   01 00 00 1B 
IL_0022:  ret
```

And for the `MyEmpty` method it is:

```
MyEmpty:
IL_0000:  ldc.i4.s    FE 
IL_0002:  newobj      15 00 00 0A 
IL_0007:  stloc.0     
IL_0008:  ldloc.0     
IL_0009:  ret         

<MyEmpty>d__0`1.System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TResult>.GetEnumerator:
IL_0000:  call        System.Environment.get_CurrentManagedThreadId
IL_0005:  ldarg.0     
IL_0006:  ldfld       0E 00 00 0A 
IL_000B:  bne.un.s    IL_0022
IL_000D:  ldarg.0     
IL_000E:  ldfld       0F 00 00 0A 
IL_0013:  ldc.i4.s    FE 
IL_0015:  bne.un.s    IL_0022
IL_0017:  ldarg.0     
IL_0018:  ldc.i4.0    
IL_0019:  stfld       0F 00 00 0A 
IL_001E:  ldarg.0     
IL_001F:  stloc.0     
IL_0020:  br.s        IL_0029
IL_0022:  ldc.i4.0    
IL_0023:  newobj      10 00 00 0A 
IL_0028:  stloc.0     
IL_0029:  ldloc.0     
IL_002A:  ret         

<MyEmpty>d__0`1.System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator:
IL_0000:  ldarg.0     
IL_0001:  call        11 00 00 0A 
IL_0006:  ret         

<MyEmpty>d__0`1.MoveNext:
IL_0000:  ldarg.0     
IL_0001:  ldfld       0F 00 00 0A 
IL_0006:  stloc.0     // CS$0$0000
IL_0007:  ldloc.0     // CS$0$0000
IL_0008:  ldc.i4.0    
IL_0009:  bne.un.s    IL_0012
IL_000B:  ldarg.0     
IL_000C:  ldc.i4.m1   
IL_000D:  stfld       0F 00 00 0A 
IL_0012:  ldc.i4.0    
IL_0013:  ret         

<MyEmpty>d__0`1.System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerator<TResult>.get_Current:
IL_0000:  ldarg.0     
IL_0001:  ldfld       12 00 00 0A 
IL_0006:  ret         

<MyEmpty>d__0`1.System.Collections.IEnumerator.Reset:
IL_0000:  newobj      System.NotSupportedException..ctor
IL_0005:  throw       

<MyEmpty>d__0`1.System.IDisposable.Dispose:
IL_0000:  ret         

<MyEmpty>d__0`1.System.Collections.IEnumerator.get_Current:
IL_0000:  ldarg.0     
IL_0001:  ldfld       12 00 00 0A 
IL_0006:  box         04 00 00 1B 
IL_000B:  ret         

<MyEmpty>d__0`1..ctor:
IL_0000:  ldarg.0     
IL_0001:  call        System.Object..ctor
IL_0006:  ldarg.0     
IL_0007:  ldarg.1     
IL_0008:  stfld       0F 00 00 0A 
IL_000D:  ldarg.0     
IL_000E:  call        System.Environment.get_CurrentManagedThreadId
IL_0013:  stfld       0E 00 00 0A 
IL_0018:  ret
```

Comment: How does that compare if you also add the IL-code that is needed voor the caching?

Comment: @Dirk Important note about that - although it produces more IL, that is not why it's not performing as well as an empty array. The main performance difference is the amount of objects being created. It's not about how much code is generated necessarily.

Comment: @mot *Every time you call MyEmpty it will create a new instance of that class.*

Comment: @Dirk True, but I didn't state otherwise. The fact that `yield` results in a lot of code is not the reason it doesn't perform as good, it's the amount of object instantiated in that flow.

Comment: @mot It may not be *the* primary reason, but it is definitely something that should come under consideration and *does* effect performance.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov I don't think it's the primary reason or any reason at all. That amount of IL could have been fast, it's the content that matters. The reason for most of this IL is related to how .NET compiles generic types, which is not at all related to the problem. It just so happens a lot of objects are being created in the process.

Comment: @mot I agree its the content that matters. But i dont think its because of the generic types, its because of the state machine that has to be emitted for `yield break`

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov Yes, but that state machine would appear only once in the IL code for all classes, if it wasn't generic. (Correct me if I'm wrong on this, I'm not strong in IL)

Comment: @mot Similar IL code will be generated for both the generic and a non-generic version: https://gist.github.com/Yuvalos/c24c51747226e9a64f6a

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov Yeah that's totally my misunderstanding then. I still insist the amount of IL means nothing to the performance here, and I doubt that was the reason to choose a static empty array. Memory allocation considerations make a lot more sense.

Answer (score 2):

It makes sense to do that because in that case you would one array for all empty instances of the same type, which will require less memory. That is why the single array instance is static.

Since an array with no elements can't be changed, it can't get dirty by any code.

Comment: arrays are immutable? Since when?

Comment: Specifically one array for all empty instances of a specific type.

Comment: Specifically, since it's an *empty* array, you don't have to worry about it getting dirty, since there are no elements to mutate. Arrays aren't immutable, but their length is, so a zero-element array is effectively immutable.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel Sorry I meant empty arrays, edited.

Comment: I didn't expect that "yield return" cost more memory than an cached array.

Comment: @AlexSiepman Since it's creating new instances for every call, it does.